How to make pyiceberg writing to aws glue iceberg table faster?
I am doing some POC to write binary data into aws glue iceberg table from local MAC.
So i selected pyiceberg instead of pyspark.
My codes are:
import os
import time

import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from pyiceberg.catalog import load_catalog
from pyiceberg.schema import Schema
from pyiceberg.types import NestedField, StringType, BinaryType
import base64
import boto3

from utils import list_files

# Create a schema for the Iceberg table
schema = Schema(
    NestedField(1, "id", StringType()),
    NestedField(2, "binary_data", BinaryType())
)

# Load the Iceberg catalog
catalog = load_catalog("glue", **{
    "type": "glue",
    "py-io-impl": "pyiceberg.io.pyarrow.PyArrowFileIO",
    "s3.access-key-id": os.getenv("AWS_KEY_ID"),
    "s3.secret-access-key": os.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"),
    "max-workers": 8
})

catalog.create_namespace_if_not_exists("test")

# Create an Iceberg table
table = catalog.create_table_if_not_exists(
    identifier="test.test-10000",
    schema=schema,
    location="s3://test/iceberg-data/")

# Load images and convert to base64
images_list = list_files("/data/test/", extension=".JPEG")
batch_size = 10000
total_batches = 10
for i in range(0, min(len(images_list), total_batches*batch_size), batch_size):
    batch = images_list[i:i + batch_size]
    ids = []
    binary_data = []
    """read binary data"""
    table_data = pa.Table.from_pydict({"id": ids, "binary_data": binary_data})
    start = time.time()
    table.append(table_data)
    # pq.write_to_dataset(table_data, root_path="s3://test/iceberg-data/", partition_cols=["id"], use_threads=True)
    end = time.time()
    print('uploaded {} in {} seconds'.format(len(ids), end - start))

How to improve the above codes to make the aws glue iceberg table writing faster? I am reading https://py.iceberg.apache.org/ but did not get clear answers.
My questions:
1, Is pyiceberg.Table thread-safe? so i can call table.append(table_data) in multiple threads or processes.
2, pq.write_to_dataset(table_data, root_path="s3://test/iceberg-data/", partition_cols=["id"], use_threads=True) => Can this statement write to partitioned iceberg table in AWS glue? or pq.write_to_dataset function just uploaded multiple parquets into s3 instead of iceberg table?
